# Create all numbers from 1-100 by using 1,3,3,7

Tags: formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

Create all the numbers from $1$ to $100$ using the numbers $1,$$3,$$3,$ and $7.$

You can only use each number once, except for the $3,$ of which you have two.
You can use addition $(x+y),$ subtraction $(x−y),$ division $(\frac{x}{y}),$ multiplication $(x\times y),$ exponentiation $(x^y),$ roots $(y\sqrt x)$, factorials $(x!)$ and ceiling and floor $(\lceil x\rceil,\lfloor y\rfloor)$.
You can combine numbers like $1$ and $7$ to $17$ etc.
Use of any types of brackets are also allowed.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi @H_D I'll try this ;) +1 for your first post ;)

Comment: We are not allowed to use brackets? :(

Comment: Use of brackets are allowed. Don't be sad.

Comment: Why the downvote? This site should not be discriminating new members of our community, please check out the Code of Conduct. We should all be community-minded and not simply drown new members with -1s. This is a legitimate question, where I do not see the point of downvoting.

Comment: @H_D I believe that we should keep the numbers in order. Otherwise it would be far to easy. I suggest stating that in the question, but anyway, the question yours, so it is up to you ;) Happy Puzzling :)

Comment: I agree with both of @OmegaKrypton's comments, although adding such a restriction after there are already 3 answers is probably bad form.  If we're talking restrictions, I would love to see concatenation banished from these puzzles in general.

Comment: Yeah, it may be too late, but lets be nice to new members and give them a chance... try to recall the time when you first joined PSE...

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I will consider them the next time I post a question.

Comment: @Bass answer is right, but should list from 1-100, which is very painstaking

Comment: I think it would be better to eliminate the floor and ceiling functions as possibilities for the rules, and just decide on the largest target number/goal number to be completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 number missing. I give up

> $0 =  7-3-3-1$
>  $1 = 7 \times 1 - 3 - 3$
>  $2 = 7 + 1 - 3 - 3$
>  $3 = \frac{7 - 1 + 3}{3}$
>  $4 = \sqrt{17-\frac{3}{3}}$
>  $5 = 3 \times (3 + 1) - 7$
>  $6 = 7 - 1 + 3 - 3$
>  $7 = 7 \times 1 - 3 + 3$
>  $8 = 7 + 1 - 3 + 3$
>  $9 = 13 + 3 - 7$
>  $10 = 3^3 - 17$
>  $11 = 17 - 3 - 3$
>  $12 = 3 \times (7 - 3) \times 1$
>  $13 = 3 \times (7 - 3) + 1$
>  $14 = 7 \times (1 + \frac{3}{3})$
>  $15 = 3 \times (7 - 3 + 1)$
>  $16 = 17 - \frac{3}{3}$
>  $17 = 17 - 3 + 3$
>  $18 = 17 + \frac{3}{3}$
>  $19 = 7 \times 3 + 1 - 3$
>  $20 = 3^3 - 7 \times 1$
>  $21 = 3^3 - 7 + 1$
>  $22 = (7-3)! - 3 + 1$
>  $23 = 7 \times 3 + 3 - 1$
>  $24 = \frac{73 - 1}{3}$
>  $25 = 33 - 7 - 1$
>  $26 = 33 - 7 \times 1$
>  $27 = 33 - 7 + 1$
>  $28 = 3 \times 7 + 3! + 1$
>  $29 = 3! \times 3! - 7 \times 1$
>  $30 = 37 - 3! - 1$
>  $31 = 37 - 3! \times 1$
>  $32 = 37 - 3! + 1$
>  $33 = 37 - 3 - 1$
>  $34 = 37 - 3 \times 1$
>  $35 = 37 - 3 + 1$
>  $36 = (7-1) \times (3+3)$
>  $37 = 3! \times (3! - 1) + 7$
>  $38 = 3! \times 7 - 3 - 1$
>  $39 = 3! \times 7 - 3 \times 1$
>  $40 = 3! \times 7 - 3 + 1$
>  $41 = 37 + 3 + 1$
>  $42 = 37 + 3! - 1$
>  $43 = 37 + 3! \times 1$
>  $44 = 37 + 3! + 1$
>  $45 = 3! \times 7 + 3 \times 1$
>  $46 = 3! \times 7 + 3 + 1$
>  $47 = 3! \times 7 + 3! - 1$
>  $48 = 3! \times 7 + 3! \times 1$
>  $49 = 7 \times (3+3+1)$
>  $50 = (7+3) \times (3!-1)$
>  $51 = 17 \times (3! - 3)$
>  $52 = 13 \times (7-3)$
>  $53 = \lfloor\sqrt{7^3}\rfloor \times 3 - 1$
>  $54 = 17 + 3^3$
>  $55 = 7 \times 3 + (3+1)!$
>  $56 = (3\times 3 - 1) \times 7$
>  $57 = 17 \times 3 + 3!$
>  $58 = \lfloor\frac{7^3}{3!}\rfloor + 1$
>  $59 = 3! \times (7+3) - 1$
>  $60 = 3! \times (7+3) \times 1$
>  $61 = 3! \times (7+3) + 1$
>  $62 = 7\times 3^3 - 1$
>  $63 = 7\times 3^3 \times 1$
>  $64 = 7\times 3^3 + 1$
>  $65 = (7+3!) \times (3!-1) $
>  $66 = 7\times 3! + (3+1)!$
>  $67 = (3+1)^3 + \lceil\sqrt{7}\rceil = 64 + 3$
>  $68 = \lfloor\frac{7^3}{3!-1}\rfloor$
>  $69 = \lceil\frac{7^3}{3!-1}\rceil$
>  $70 = (7 + 3) \times (3! + 1)$
>  $71 = 71 -3 + 3$
>  $72 = (3! + 3!) \times (7-1)$
>  $73 = 73 + \lfloor\frac{1}{3}\rfloor$
>  $74 = 3^{3+1} - 7$
>  $75 = 73 + 3 - 1$
>  $76 = 73 + 3 \times 1$
>  $77 = 73 + 3 + 1$
>  $78 = 3! \times (7 + 3!) \times 1$
>  $79 = 3! \times (7 + 3!) + 1$
>  $80 = 3^{7-3} - 1$
>  $81 = 3^{7-3} \times 1$
>  $82 = 3^{7-3} + 1$
>  $83 = 7 \times (3! + 3!) - 1$
>  $84 = 7 \times (3! + 3!) \times 1$
>  $85 = 7 \times (3! + 3!) + 1$
>  $86 = 73 + 13$
>  $87 =  \lceil{\sqrt{\sqrt{13^7}}}\rceil - 3 = \lceil{89.00222..}\rceil - 3$
>  $88 =  3^{3+1} + 7$
>  $89 =  13 \times 7 - \lceil\sqrt{3}\rceil$
>  $90 =  13 \times 7 - \lfloor\sqrt{3}\rfloor$
>  $91 =  (3!+3!+1) \times 7$
>  $92 =  13 \times 7 + \lfloor\sqrt{3}\lfloor$
>  $93 =  13 \times 7 + \lceil\sqrt{3}\lceil$
>  $94 =  13 \times 7 + 3$
>  $95 =  $
>  $96 =  17 \times 3! - 3!$
>  $97 =  73 + (3+1)!$
>  $98 =  71 + 3^3$
>  $99 =  (3! - 1)! - 3\times 7$
>  $100 =  31 \times 3 + 7$

**Bonus**:

> If we allow `log` functions we can generate every number like this:
>  $x = \log_{\frac{1}{\lfloor\sqrt7\rfloor}}\left({\log_3\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots\sqrt{3\,}\,}\,}}_\text{x square roots}}\right)$
>  
>  This is equivalent to
>  
>  $x = \log_{\frac12}\left({\log_3{3^{\frac{1}{2^x}}}}\right)$
>  
>  Going further:
>  
>  $x = \log_{\frac12}\left({\frac{1}{2^x}}\right)$

Comment: I think for 78 and 79, you meant $3!\times (7+3!)\times 1$ and $3!\times (7+3!)+1$, right?

Comment: You're welcome. It's kind of my responsibility to do so I guess?

Comment: Very close! You can do it!!

Comment: Here's a silly one for you: $95: 1+ \lfloor \sqrt{ \sqrt{ \sqrt{ \lfloor \sqrt{ 337 } \rfloor ! } } } \rfloor$

Answer (score 4):

This puzzle is a bit too broad, so I only have three example numbers below. I'm sure you can figure out what the rest might look like.

> $36 = \lfloor{\sqrt{1337}}\rfloor$
>
> $11 = \lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{(\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{(\lfloor{\sqrt{1337}}\rfloor)!}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor)!}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor$
>
>  $79 = \lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{(\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{(\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{(\lfloor{\sqrt{1337}}\rfloor)!}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor)!}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor}}\rfloor)!}}\rfloor}}\rfloor$

Comment: Surely I didn't think of this possibility. Well, fascinating.

Comment: I guess "drop the bass" has a whole new meaning in here

Answer (score 3):

Trying my best to arrange the numbers in order:

1-10:

> 1= $1*-(3+3-7)$
> 2= $1-(3+3-7)$
> 3= $13-3-7$
> 4= $1*floor(\sqrt{3})*-(3-7)$
> 5= $1^3*3+floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 6= $13*floor(\sqrt{3})-7$
> 7= $13+floor(\sqrt{3})-7$
> 8= $13-3-floor(7)$
> 9= $1*3^{\sqrt{(-3+7)}}$
> 10= $1+3^{\sqrt{(-3+7)}}$

11-20:

> 11= $13-floor(\sqrt{3})*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 12= $13+floor(\sqrt{3})-floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 13= $13+ceil(\sqrt{3})-floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 14= $(1+3)!-3-7$
> 15= $13+floor(\sqrt{3})*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 16= $(1+3)^{\sqrt{(-3+7)}}$
> 17= $13-3+7$
> 18= $1*3*3*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 19= $13+3*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 20= $(-1+3)*(3+7)$

21-30:

> 21= $1-floor(\sqrt{3})+3*7$
> 22= $1*floor(\sqrt{3})+3*7$
> 23= $1+floor(\sqrt{3})+3*7$
> 24= $1*3+3*7$
> 25= $(-1+3+3)^{floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 26= $13*floor(\sqrt{3})*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 27= $1*3*3*ceil(\sqrt{7})$
> 28= $-1+3^3+floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 29= $-1+3*(3+7)$
> 30= $1*3*(3+7)$

31-40:

> 31= $1+3*(3+7)$
> 32= $1*3^{3+floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 33= $1+3^{3+floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 34= $1*(-3)+37$
> 35= $1-3+37$
> 36= $-1*floor(\sqrt{3})+37$
> 37= $1*floor(\sqrt{3})+37$
> 38= $1+floor(\sqrt{3})+37$
> 39= $-1+3+37$
> 40= $1*3+37$

41-50:

> 41= $1+3+37$
> 42= $1*(3+3)*7$
> 43= $1+(3+3)*7$
> 44= $1+3!+37$
> 45= $(1+3)!+3*7$
> 46= $13*3+7$
> 47= $-1+3!+3!*7$
> 48= $(1+3)!*floor(\sqrt{3})*floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 49= $(1+3+3)*7$
> 50= $(-1+3!)*(3+7)$

51-60:

> 51= $1*floor(\sqrt{3!!})+floor(\sqrt{\sqrt{3!!}})^{floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 52= $1+floor(\sqrt{3!!})+floor(\sqrt{\sqrt{3!!}})^{floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 53= $1+ceil(\sqrt{3!!})+floor(\sqrt{\sqrt{3!!}})^{floor(\sqrt{7})}$
> 54= $1*3*3*floor(\sqrt{7})!$
> 55= $(-1+3!)(floor(\sqrt{\sqrt{3!!}}+ceil(\sqrt{7})!)$
> 56= $(-1+3!+3)*7$
> 57= $(-1+floor(\sqrt{3!!}))*ceil(\sqrt{3})+7$
> 58= $-(1+3)*3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 59= $-13+ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7})$
> 60= $-13+3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$

61-70:

> 61= $-1*3*3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 62= $-(1+3)*ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 63= $1*3*3*7$
> 64= $1+3*3*7$
> 65= $-1*3-ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 66= $-1-3-ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 67= $-1*3-floor(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 68= $-1-floor(\sqrt{3})*floor(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 69= $-1*3/3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 70= $1*3/3*floor(\sqrt{7!})$

71-80:

> 71= $1*3/3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 72= $-1+3*floor(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 73= $1*3*floor(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 74= $1+3*floor(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 75= $-1+3*ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 76= $1*3*ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 77= $1+3*ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 78= $-1+3*3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 79= $1*3*3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 80= $1+3*3+floor(\sqrt{7!})$

81-90:

> 81= $-1+3!+3!+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 82= $1*3!+3!+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 83= $1+3!+3!+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 84= $-1+3^ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 85= $1*3^ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$
> 86= $1+3^ceil(\sqrt{3})+floor(\sqrt{7!})$

Answer (score 1):

Extending Omega Krypton's answer with 8 to 15, keeping 1,3,3,7 in order. I use $\circ$ to display concatenation:

> $8 = 1+3-3+7$
> $9 = \lceil 1* \sqrt[3]{3}\rceil+7$
> $10 = 1 \circ  \lfloor 3/3 \circ  7 \rfloor$
> $11 = 1\circ 3- \lceil \sqrt[3]{7} \rceil$
> $12 = 1\circ 3- \lceil 3/7 \rceil$
> $13 = 1\circ 3+ \lfloor 3/7 \rfloor$
> $14 = 1\circ 3+ \lceil 3/7 \rceil$
> $15 = 1\circ 3+ \lceil \sqrt[3]{7} \rceil$

Answer (score 1):

Work in progress, I'm trying to avoid using ceil, floor and root, so far so good but I don't think it's possible for some big numbers. I could have made some mistakes though.

1-10:

> $1=(1+3+3)/7$
> $2=1+7-3-3$
> $3=3*3-7+1$
> $4=(31-3)/7$
> $5=3!+3!-7/1$
> $6=37-31$
> $7=7+(3-3)*1$
> $8=17-3*3$
> $9=7+1+3/3$
> $10=3!*3-7-1$

11-20:

> $11=17-3-3$
> $12=3!*3-7+1$
> $13=7+3+3/1$
> $14=7+3+3+1$
> $15=7*3-3!/1$
> $16=33-17$
> $17=17-3+3$
> $18=3*7-3/1$
> $19=3*7-3+1$
> $20=3!+3!+7+1$

21-30:

> $21=31-7-3$
> $22=17+3!-3$
> $23=17+3+3$
> $24=37-13$
> $25=3*7+3+1$
> $26=3!*3+7+1$
> $27=(7-3)!+3/1$
> $28=(7-3)!+3+1$
> $29=3!*3!-7/1$
> $30=3!*3!-7+1$

31-40:

> $31=7*(3+1)+3$
> $32=13*3-7$
> $33=37-3-1$
> $34=37-3/1$
> $35=37-3+1$
> $36=(7-1)*(3+3)$
> $37=13+(7-3)!$
> $38=71-33$
> $39=37+3-1$
> $40=37+3/1$

41-50:

> $41=37+3+1$
> $42=73-31$
> $43=7*(3+3)+1$
> $44=7*3!+3-1$
> $45=7*3!+3/1$
> $46=13*3+7$
> $47=7*3!+3!-1$
> $48=(7+1)*(3+3)$
> $49=7*(3+3+1)$
> $50=(7+3)*3!-1$

51-60: (WIP)

> $51=$
> $52=$
> $53=$
> $54=17*3+3$
> $55=$
> $56=$
> $57=$
> $58=$
> $59=$
> $60=(13+7)*3$

61-70: (WIP)

> $61=$
> $62=7*3*3-1$
> $63=7*3*3/1$
> $64=7*3*3+1$
> $65=$
> $66=$
> $67=$
> $68=37+31$
> $69=73-3-1$
> $70=(73-3)/1$

71-80: (WIP)

> $71=73-3+1$
> $72=71+3/3$
> $73=$
> $74=$
> $75=$
> $76=$
> $77=71+3+3$
> $78=$
> $79=$
> $80=$

81-90: (WIP)

> $81=$
> $82=$
> $83=$
> $84=$
> $85=7*13-3!$
> $86=31*3-7$
> $87=$
> $88=7*13-3$
> $89=$
> $90=$

91-100 (WIP)

> $91=$
> $92=$
> $93=$
> $94=7*13+3$
> $95=$
> $96=$
> $97=7*13+3!$
> $98=$
> $99=$
> $100=31*3+7$