# Use only 1 2 6 7 to write expressions that equal 31 32 33 34

Tags: formation-of-numbers

> Construct expressions that equal $31$, $32$, $33$, and $34$ using the numbers $1$, $2$, $6$, and $7$.  In each expression, each number must be used exactly once. You addition ($+$), subtraction ($-$), multiplication ($\times$), and division ($\div$). You may also use parentheses.

I have found several ways to do this for 33 but not for the other answers.

Comment: Hi welcome to Puzzling SE! These kinds of questions might be a little too math-y for the sight, but I would need verfied inputs from more experienced users

Comment: @North this just seems like your typical "use *these numbers* and *these operations* to make *this total*" puzzle to me

Comment: @Hugh I guess I'll retract my flag then since it's not off-topic per se...? Or should I keep the flag?

Comment: @North I'd say retract, I guess? It's basically like one of [these](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/78994/) puzzles, but with $1$, $2$, $6$, and $7$, and different totals. [edit: JonMark Perry added the tag formation-of-numbers, I think that tag suits the puzzle well.]

Comment: Okay, I've retracted the flag, but in all honesty (I'm sorry to say this) but I'm still not a huge fan of these puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $31=(7-2)\times6+1$
>  $32=(7+1)\times(6-2)$
>  $33=7\times(6-1)-2$
>  $34=(7-1)\times6-2$