# Combine 1,3,3,7 to get 10

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

I tried lots of combinations but could not find a solution. Each number has to be used exactly once, the allowed mathematical operators are

- Addition: **+**
- Subtraction: **-**
- Negation: (unary prefix) **-**
- Multiplication: *****
- Division: **/**
- Grouping with parentheses: **(** **)**

All other operations (including the often implicitly accepted "concatenating initial digits to create a multi-digit number") are disallowed.

Comment: With some low-effort answers already coming in, I clarified the intent of the operator list you gave, hope this is what you meant. Don't want anyone saying "the parens can be used as the [choose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) operator, so  ${7 - 3 + 1 \choose 3} = 10$", now do we :-)

Comment: @Bass that was used in [a puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92773/building-the-perfect-number-28-with-fractions-part2) before indeed, haha

Comment: Is raising to a power allowed (see my answer)?

Comment: Is "concatenating initial digits to create a word" allowed? Because LEET speak is 10 out of 10.

Comment: Maybe so, but "10 out of 10" or 10 / 10 is 1 :-)

Answer (score 48):

As quite standard in this kind of hard number puzzle, we can:

> use addition on a fraction: $$\left(\frac{7}{3}+1\right)\times 3 = 10$$

Another example of this form being the only solution is:

> Use 1, 2, 3, 8 to make 28

with the unique (up to commutation) solution being:

> $$\left(\frac{1}{2}+3\right)\times 8 = 28$$

Comment: Dammit, I just spent a good ten minutes moving numbers around in my head and felt _so_ proud to have finally got it – only to realise it was right there in the highest-voted answer!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you should still be proud if you find it yourself! :D

Answer (score 2):

If concatenation is allowed, then one solution is

> $31 - 7*3 = 31 - 21 = 10$

Comment: If indices/powers were permitted as well as concatenation, there's another possible solution in [this question on the site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/78997/60644).

Comment: That was actually my initial answer, but since 3³ is 3^3 and uses a "^", which isn't allowed, I chose to go for the answer above.

Comment: Unfortunately, concatenations do not seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The following is trivial, but (at least up to now) not explicitly forbidden by OP's definition:

> in octal system: $ 1 + 3 - 3 + 7 = 10 $

Comment: Yes, I had that one, too :) Unfortunately not allowed. Also 1+3+3+7 =10 in tetradecimal would be nice.

Comment: I guess $7-3-1=10_3$ is also no go?